# How can a minor own and operate an LLC with as little adult involvement as possible?

Tags: united-states, minor, oregon, limited-liability-company

Note: I am going to talk to a lawyer before I actually do this, but I would like to have some idea of the best option before I start.

If a minor wants to start a business selling things on eBay as an LLC, how can the LLC be set up so the minor does as much of the work as possible, receives as much of the money as possible, and pays as much of the taxes as possible, with a parent involved as needed for legal requirements?

Comment: E-Bay does not allow minors to even access the site, not as a person, not with a guardian'S consent, not as an LLC. Besides, as an auction house, the accessing of the junior might be a violation of law too.

Comment: @Trish: https://www.ebay.com/help/policies/identity-policies/age-limits-policy "A person under 18 can use an adult's account with the permission of the account holder. However, the account holder is responsible for everything done with that account."

Comment: they can't have an account themselves.

Comment: @Trish but does that mean an LLC owned by a minor can't have an account if the person who agrees to the ToS is an adult authorized to bind the LLC?

Comment: Read the ToS. Hire a lawyer.

Comment: The problem that you have as a minor is not so much legality, but the fact that you are your guardian can. Void any contracts that you sign, and therefore people often don’t want to do business with you.

Comment: @gnasher729 that's why the parent is involved. The idea is for the parent to agree to contracts and the minor to do everything else.

Comment: @gnasher729 In this scenario it would be the LLC entering into contracts, not the minor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guardian (usually your parent) can practically override anything you do. So you can’t do anything in practice  if your parents know about it and are against it.

Whether you can start an LLC as a minor I don’t know. The fact that you could escape all otherwise binding contracts makes it unlikely. EBay apparently refuses to enter contracts with minors.

Obviously your parents can set up an LLC and enter contracts with eBay, while leaving you with all the work to do, allowing you to put profits into a bank account in your name and taking losses out of your savings. Ultimately they will be legally responsible, but as long as everything is fine (you do all the work, it doesn’t keep you from going to school or is just to much work for a minor, and you make some profit going into your bank account) this is alright. You’d have to make sure that taxes are handled correctly; the LLC can pay salary and dividends to you.  Shortly after you are a legal adult, your parents can sell you the company for a dollar.

Be aware that your parents can quite likely rip you off legally if they are that kind of parent.

Comment: Note that the last issue (being ripped off) can be avoided by the creation of a trust. This also avoids the need for the company to be later sold to the minor (instead the beneficiary can simply collapse the trust and require the legal interest to be transferred). This might not even be necessary. In England for example, a minor can hold company shares directly, and the minimum age for being a company director is 16. A minor under 16 could appoint parents as directors but still retain overall control of the company via voting rights on the shares.

Comment: I trust my parents to not rip me off, and I'm okay with them being able to override anything I do.

Answer (score -3):

[Google says sure](https://legalbeagle.com/13306269-can-a-minor-own-a-membership-in-an-llc.html)

All contracting must be done by an adult.

Comment: I am aware that is is possible; i was asking about possible ways to do it.

Comment: I downvoted because this doesn't answer the question. You've answered with "yes" but there was no yes/no question. Also, your second paragraph doesn't make sense. For OP's scenario it would be a LLC entering into contracts, not a natural person. Perhaps you meant to say that only adults can cause LLCs to enter into contracts; a citation would be helpful if that is what you are saying.